# How can I measure the output of a high voltage generator/stun gun

Tags: dc, high-voltage, measurement

I recently bought a ["400kV" high voltage generator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XMNQ479). Obviously this thing does not produce a 400kV output, but is there a way to measure it? I know there is the air gap way when it says 30kV/cm air, but this is not that reliable since the dielectric strength of air can vary.

I also looked into a voltage divider, the power can be worked out (if we make a guess that the actual voltage will be around 30kV,) but the 30kV voltage might be too high and jump over the resistors (in the short pulse it will give.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 40x of [10kV 15MΩ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DGGQ8WS) resistors in series, and on the last one you would get 10kV across it, you could then use another divider on the last resistor to get down to something meaningful like 1000V or 500V which could be measured by most scopes or DMM's

Another thing you might try is find a high resistance material like kapton or FR4 and see if you could make a divider out of that. You might be able to just put a strip of copper foil on a large lenghth (like 1m) at the 1:40 or 1:100 position and make a divider out of that.

Comment: If you put your chain of resistors into a silicone rubber tube, seal the end, fill with transformer oil it makes your high voltage resistor a little easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You use multiple series resistor and ensure that there is sufficient clearance on the circuit board between each resistor's terminals. For instance, in a design I recently did for 50 kV, the total series resistance in the upper half of the potential divider was 2.5 GΩ. The lower resistor was chosen to produce 2.5 volts at the junction when 50 kV is present. I think it was around 100 kΩ from memory.

I chose the values to keep the power dissipation down to a watt i.e. 50 kV across 2.5 GΩ is a power of 1 watt. You might also choose to put a 100 pF capacitor across the 100 kΩ resistor to balance the parasitic capacitance of the upper resistors in series.

Individually I decided to use resistors that were rated at 2000 volts hence, I needed 25 of them (100 MΩ each).

> *if we make a guess that the actual power will be around 30kV*

Power is measured in watts or kW.

Answer (score 1):

A spark gap with spherical (or at least smooth and rounded) contacts can give you a good idea of the upper bound on the voltage. Pointed or spikey contacts could lead you to believe the open-circuit voltage is higher than it actually is.

Assuming that yields the expected 20-30kV maximum (confirmed for safety), you can purchase a single [50kV 1GΩ 5% resistor](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/ohmite/MOX-5N-131007JE/4251632) and use that with a multimeter with 10MΩ  input impedance to give an approximately 100:1 probe, so on the 500VDC range you can measure 50kV. It's not as good as a $400 [Fluke HV probe](https://www.itm.com/product/fluke_80k_40_high_voltage_probe) but also < 1/10 the cost. The resistor is 130mm (~5") long, quite a monster.

The modules typically have 0.5GΩ resistor across the output so such a probe will have some loading effect.

Be sure to take appropriate precautions with the high voltage, it could cause a painful shock or easily damage (ie. destroy) a meter if it finds its way directly to the input.

Answer (score 0):

A generating voltmeter can be used.

https://www.eeeguide.com/generating-voltmeter-principle-and-construction/